# How to distinguish Alt press and Alt + 3 press

Tags: qt

I have a problem how to distinguish Alt press and Alt + 3 press.
I have two diference action.
Alt - show menu bar
Alt + 3 - add 3th pane into my main window.

How do I distinguish between these two events? Problém is (in this moment) that when I press Alt + 3. Booth actions is called.

```
void cc::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    switch (event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_3:
            if(event->modifiers() == Qt::AltModifier)
            {
                if(ui->widget_3->isVisible())
                    ui->widget_3->hide();
                else
                    ui->widget_3->show();
            }
            break;
        case Qt::Key_Alt:
            if(!menuBar()->isVisible())
                ui->menuBar->show();
            else
                ui->menuBar->hide();
            break;
        default: QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I known, that I can use counter and wait some time and show menu when time is end (2s). If user press Alt+3 and if he was not pressed it for 2s, I show 3. pane only. If they press alt only for 3s, I show menu.

It seems kind of complicated. Can't I do something simpler?

Comment: I think the only sane way is to have the "ALT only" action react on keyReleaseEvent(). Here e.g. in Firefox Alt vs. Alt + 3 doesn't depend on timing (I think that'd be horrible), but Alt fires if I release Alt and no other key was pressed. Did you try to simply use QAction with the respective shortcuts? Maybe it just does the right thing.

Comment: Frank, You have right. This is exactly what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the code related to Alt-only shortcut in a `void cc::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * event)` event. this event happens once a key is released.

So when you press Alt, nothing happens, if you release it, the "show menu bar" will happen, but if you keep pressing and press 3, then the other code will happen.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I test it, but it looks like a solution which I looking for.